# Android splash screen spin or swirl

Tags: android, splash-screen

Hi I was curious if anybody knew of a way to make the splash screen `spin/swirl` when app was ran for the first time. The image im wanting to spin/swirl is a png.

Answer (score 6):

For a swirl you would have to create your own animation but for rotate you just animate the ImageView.

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(1000);

ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

There are other methods of [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) and [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) that you can use to customize the animation.

Comment: Thanks @Robby Pond

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just create the image which you want to rotate.
and just write the following code in you splash screen.
*note:-here 2160f is the total degree of rotation
         and 3000 is the time of rotation....here it is 3 seconds

```
ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        image.animate().rotation(2160f).setDuration(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> SAME CODE ON ANDROID KOTLIN

```
    val iv : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.title_pic)
    val rotation :RotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(0f,360f)
    rotation.repeatCount = Animation.ZORDER_NORMAL  // here you can use any Animation effect
    rotation.duration = 1000
    iv.startAnimation(rotation)
```